Handle cocoapod static and dynamic libraries in expo project for ios
I am using expo sdk 51, expo version 6.3.10
iOS
I have created library which wraps my native ios xcframework with expo. Within example app which was automatically generated for the lib Cocoapods works fine and can in stall my native library, but when i create a new separate project and integrate that lib there and run pod install i am getting
Unable to install vendored xcframework MyCustomReactKit for Pod MyCustomReact, because it contains both static and dynamic frameworks.
Podfiles for both of project are the same.
Did anyone face similar problem and how did you solve it?
